# How to update child table while updating parent in one to one mapping using rest call

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa

```java
@RestController
public class EmpController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService empService;

    @RequestMapping("/addData")
    void AddEmpData(@RequestBody Employee emp)
    {

        empService.addData(emp);
    }

}
```

this is my rest controller. I'm able to add data to parent table emp . Now I want my child table Empdetails to get automatically updated whenever I insert a new row in the emp table. How to achieve this.

```java
@Service
public class EmployeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empResp;

    @Override
    public void addData(Employee emp) {
        empResp.save(emp);      
    }

}
```

my parent class

public Employee(String empName) {

```
    this.empName = empName;
}
@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long empId;

private String empName;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "emp")
private EmployeeDetails ed;
```

//getter and setter

my child class

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long eId;
private String empCity;


private String salary;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkeyEmpId", nullable = false)

private Employee emp;
```

//getter  setter

Comment: Can you add some code of your `addData` method of `EmployeeService`

Comment: i just edited have a look

Comment: Is emp.Empdetails == null?
try create and assign the details before save.

Comment: I did but then I'm getting foreign key constraint error

Comment: Can you add more information about the entities involved?

Comment: Please post your entity classes, so that we can check your mapping

Comment: i added kindly check

Answer (score 0):

If you EmployeeDetails object is null, no record will be saved on database. If you want to save a default data on EmployeeDetails table, you should initialize the object as below:

```
private EmployeeDetails ed = new EmployeeDetails ();
```

Try it and explain it to us.